# VBA PivotTable Error: When spreadsheet is emailed or downloaded, my macros will not run

Tags: excel, vba

all. I completed a project for a class and all of my macros will not run on my professor's PC. We have checked several times that my professor's security settings are correct and all macros are enabled. When macros are run, the following snippet of my VBA code is highlighted as the error when selecting "debug":

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'Raw Data'!R1C1:R68615C17", Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
    :="", TableName:="PivotTable1234567890", DefaultVersion:=8`
```

Any idea how to fix this problem? I'm happy to post the current workbook if that makes resolving this issue easier. Thanks!!!

Comment: The `Version:=8` and `DefaultVersion:=8` may be problematic. What is the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add a line break between the variable name and `:=` as you need a space before the underscore. Just try changing the line break slightly after TableDestination. i.e.  `TableDestination:="" _ ` and you may find the error resolves.